# How to get parameter from Resource route with $request or any other method?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my Resource route:

```
     Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController');
```

This is the Url I am requesting for edit from a view the project with id

```
     projects/$project->id/edit/
```

Now how will I get the parameter

```
     $project-id
```

form the Url into my ProjectsController edit() method with Request $request or other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have Route Handler In Your Contttroller:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id ){
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id)
    ...
    [DO Whatewer You Want]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function edit( $id ){
    $project = Project::find($id)
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of the implicit model binding:

```
public function edit( Project $project ){
    //$project is your model instance
}
```

More on this topic here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding